# How to redownload macOS Mojave if software update claims the downloaded package is damaged?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macos-mojave

Try to upgrade to macOS majave, but it claims the downloaded package damaged, how to delete it and redownload it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried simply repeating the process?

Comment: Yes, every time it claims the downloaded package corrupted.

Comment: Have you ruled out a bad package at the source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the downloaded file. It's in Applications, so just deleted it and redownload.

[image]

Comment: This would be a better answer if it described how you found the relevant file. … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But it is found by randomly clicks, so...